# 1C. PHP Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0, referer

Tags: php, битрикс, 1с

При вызове метода 1С вылетает ошибка

> PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0, referer

Сам метод возвращает документ для печати. Пытался увеличить `memory_limit` но это не помогло

Comment: у меня такая же проблема но /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini не где не могу найти

Comment: Такая же проблема, `output_buffering` в конфиге имеет значение `0`

Answer (score 2):

В файле `/etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini` отключите `output_buffering` для php-cli, он у вас скорее всего установлен в 4096, а должен быть отключен по умолчанию.

Comment: Решение не помагает, `output_buffering` в конфиге имеет значение `0`